# Blender animation different when imported to Unity

Tags: animation, unity

Animation in Blender: http://gph.is/2aCbBB4
Animation in Unity: http://gph.is/2affwlR

Anyone know why the entire model moves in unity but only the vertex group i created moves in blender? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved: the solution was to animate the rotation of the bone instead of the location